# Replace two space indentation with tabs

Tags: indentation, substitute

I'd like to replace all two-space indents with tabs

I can't do `:%s/  /^I/g` bc this replaces within lines too.

I can't do `:%s/^  /^I/g` bc this replaces only the first two spaces of each line, not each level of indentation.

If there were a way to count how many matches were found, something like this could work `:%s/^\(  \)*/\count^I/g`, but I don't know whether any of that exists and I've tried looking it up but couldn't find it.

Is there a way I can replace X spaces at the start of a line with X/2 tabs?

Comment: Another great way would be to use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144284/force-vi-vim-to-use-leading-tabs-only-on-retab/5144480#5144480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `:h sub-replace-special`:

```
%s@^ \+@\=repeat("\t", strlen(submatch(0)) / &ts)
```

Comment: What's `&ts` here?

Comment: The value of `'tabstop'`.

Comment: I'm using `%s@^\(  \)\+@\=repeat("\t", strlen(submatch(0)) / 2)` bc the answer gets rid of single spaces. Thanks for showing me this section of `:s`